# flickering with UserControl backgroundimage in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, visual-studio-2015, user-controls

I have a WinForm that looks like the following. It essentially uses a `User Control` and `FlowLayoutPanel` to fill a `DataGridView`.

The user control has three `Labels` that are bound to a `DataTable` and the UC's `BackgroundImage` property is also set according to the `DataTable`.

This is the `Form`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
    DataTable DT = null;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.DataSourceChanged += dataGridView1_DataSourceChanged;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DT = GetRooms();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DT;
    }
    private void dataGridView1_DataSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            UCBind ucb = new UCBind(row, imageList1);
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(ucb);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the `User Control`:

```
public partial class UCBind : UserControl
{
    ImageList imgList { get; set; }

    public UCBind()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public UCBind(DataRow row, ImageList imglist)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (row != null)
        {
            imgList = imglist;
            DisplayData(row);
        }
    }

    public void DisplayData(DataRow row)
    {
        label1.Text = row.Field<string>(7) + "";
        label2.Text = row.Field<string>(8);
        label3.Text = row.Field<string>(9);
        BackgroundImage = imgList.Images[0]; // I just display an image here

    }
}
```

The issue is that there's quite a bit of flickering in the part of the background where the labels are, at the top of the User Control. It eventually fixes itself and everything looks correct, but the flickering is very noticeable:

[image]
After about a second it looks correct:

[image]

Is there a way to eliminate this flickering? I also set `flowLayoutPanel` `AutoScroll` to true, and I see tons of flickering also.

I've tried [this solution](http://www.richard-banks.org/2007/09/how-to-create-flicker-free.html) and another similar one that sets `DoubleBuffered` property to true, but I still see lots of flickering.

Thanks.

Comment: Try a add a `flowLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout()` and `flowLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout()` before and after the loop or go for using `flowLayoutPanel1Controls.AddRange(..)`. And adding a `this.Doublebuffered = true;` to the `UCBind` constructor(s) is also recommended.

Comment: I added `this.Doublebuffered = true` and it worked well. If you want, you can add it as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `UserControl` holds not only a few `Labels` but also a `BackgroundImage` it will greatly profit from [DoubleBuffering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To activate it you need to add this line to each of the contructors:

```
public UCBind()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Doublebuffered = true;
}
```

and:

```
public UCBind(DataRow row, ImageList imglist)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Doublebuffered = true;

    if (row != null)
    {
        imgList = imglist;
        DisplayData(row);
    }
}
```

When adding the UCs you can speed up the process by either:

- enclosing the loop the adds to the FlowLayoutPanel with a `flowLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();` and `flowLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();`
- or you can collect the UCs in a `List<UCBind>` and then use the `AddRange` method to add them all in one go.

Here is the second option with the modified loop:

```
List<UCBind> ucs = new List<UCBind>();
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    UCBind ucb = new UCBind(row, imageList1);
    ucs.Add(ucb);
}
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.AddRange(ucs.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help.